# Stop the push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My app push notification pushing from C# Application using device token.

Once user uninstall app on device, I want to stop the push notification. Yeah of course it's working fine.

Again installed same app. But it is receiving previous user notification without login.
How to solve this problem?…

I have refereed this link http://42spikes.com/post/Sending-Apple-Push-Notifications-from-a-C-Application.aspx

My Question :

1) Is it possible to call any method while uninstalling/installing time? (possible means can I hit web services and reset device token value?).

2) Any Other idea to solve this problem while installing or uninstalling time?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there is no method fired when a user uninstalls your app.
2. Yes,
   Apple has a service where you can check wether tokens are still
   valid.

The option you want to implement in your C# Application is [The Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3):

> The Apple Push Notification Service includes a feedback service to give you information about failed push notifications. When a push notification cannot be delivered because the intended app does not exist on the device, the feedback service adds that device’s token to its list. Push notifications that expire before being delivered are not considered a failed delivery and don’t impact the feedback service. By using this information to stop sending push notifications that will fail to be delivered, you reduce unnecessary message overhead and improve overall system performance.